# sort by two fields not behaving right

Tags: bash, sorting, csv, gnu, delimiter

First off, I have already read about locale's effect on sorting, and I believe my error is exempt from those influences.

I am trying to sort data in the format

```
8hjk.apple
5ykh.orange
6faq.pear
```

by the second field first (fruit), then by the LETTERS of the first field. I have made many attempts, most of which will sort by fruit, but not by the first field.

```
sort -t "." -k 2,2  -k1.2,1.3
```

everything i've checked tells me this is the way, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way

```
sort -t. -k2,2 -k1,1 < file.txt
```

Where `-k2,2` means to use the fields from #2 to #2, i.e. only the second field.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I've tried it that way, it still doesn't want to behave though!

Comment: doing this causes it to sort by the third field, as the . is an essential delimiter.

Comment: @Aiden, would you mind trying again. edited the answer. i have no way of testing it but to my knowledge it should work just fine.

Comment: @Aiden, that's strange! are you sure there is no leading white spaces?

Comment: @Rahul... positive! i've tried running it with -b too just to be safe. I'll have to try in on my cloud workspace later... maybe its a system error. Thanks for your help! I really appreciate your time!

Answer (score 0):

You command works, you're just not giving it enough input to see that it's working. With more data:

```
sort -t. -k2,2 -k1.2,1.4  <<END
1ykh.orange
2ded.apple
3mno.orange
4bcd.apple
5faq.pear
6mnk.orange
END
```

```
4bcd.apple
2ded.apple
6mnk.orange
3mno.orange
1ykh.orange
5faq.pear
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me :( Here is an example of the output `1A27.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -10
1CX2.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -3.8  
2JEY.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -5.8  
1HWK.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -6.7  
1TGM.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -6.5  
1VRT.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -6.2  
1B59.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -7.1  
2F16.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -7.9  
2HT8.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -7.3  
3MHJ.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -7  
1X70.vegfr2_decoys*2334 -7.2`  sorry i cant get the line breaks right. but it sorts by the second field well (there are thousands of truncated results), but the first field values are seemingly random

Comment: what version of `sort` do you have?